# Scale my item image to fit the screen properly

Tags: android, xml, image, scale

So I got a problem scaling my image to fit my home screen appropriately.

Here are some screenshots.

Height problem

[image: The height is not as big as it should be]

Width problem

[image: Here the height is right but not the width]

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

XML Item code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.inthessaloniki.cityguide.view.SelectorRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_clickable_item_bg_inverse">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.inthessaloniki.cityguide.view.SelectorRelativeLayout>
```

I want the images to match the parent width but scale their heigth accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The scaleType="fitXY" forces image to fix to screen and does not keep aspect ratio.

Try  this instead

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out a solution.
Here it is in case someone had the same problem.

I used scaleY and padding to fit the images accordingly.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_poi_list_item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:scaleY="1.25"/>
```